# How do we use MINUS with array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, subtraction

as function `MINUS(value1, value2)` it only has 2 arguments

Do we have function like `MINUS(array)` and minus each row of an array?

Or need to use app-script to create the custom function?

my full length formula is

```
=MINUS(FILTER(C5:C20,LEFT(A5:A20)=" "=FALSE))
```

Column C contains numbers

Column A contains texts

which will always be changing

[image]

Comment: Could you give us an example plz? As far as I can see =minus(a1:a10), say, would be the same as =a1-sum(a2:a10) ?

Comment: Yes, like "=a1-sum(a2:a10)" but it's more tricky when using with dynamic array which I also use FILTER. I'll screenshot the expect outcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my rather simple-minded comment above I suggested the 'MINUS' function for a range A1:A10 would just be

```
A1-sum(A2:A10)
```

Another way of doing it would be

```
2*A1-sum(a1:a10)
```

Applying this second formula to your filtered data gives:

```
=2*array_constrain(filter(D:D,left(B:B)<>" ",D:D<>""),1,1)-ARRAYFORMULA(sumif(left(B:B,1),"<> ",D:D))
```

In other words, find the first row with data in it, multiply by two and subtract the sum of all the data.

[image]

Comment: As you know, you can just write left(B:B) like I did first time - for some reason I wrote left (B:B,1) the second time but not necessary to put the '1' in.

Comment: yes, I once put LEFT(1 argument) on accident. It worked as I wanted to, then I always use it shorter. I used the formula for this template I was working on https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qBTwSMjlkcVhVcENJTR461Nvgc_T91tbLzyexZd1ZpE/edit#gid=2016395731 and it is free. By the way I just started to do this and I hope it'll be helpful to anyone

Answer (score 1):

use minus operator instead of function like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A10 - B1:B10)
```

or you can use `QUERY` like:

```
=QUERY(A1:B10, "select A - B")

=QUERY({A1:B10}, "select Col1 - Col2")
```